# Excluding YouTube links from urlize filter and handling iframe tags in Django template

Tags: django

I'm facing an issue in my Django template where I want to exclude YouTube links from the django urlize filter and ensure that the remaining content, including YouTube videos embedded with iframe tags, is properly displayed. Here's a simplified version of my template and view

here's the template
`<div class="comment-body">{{comment.body|safe|linebreaksbr|urlize}}</div>`

here is the way i converted the youtube link to iframe:

```
    yt_link = re.compile(r'(https?://)?(www\.)?((youtu\.be/)|(youtube\.com/watch/?\?v=))([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)', re.I)
    yt_embed = '<iframe width="460" height="215" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{0}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'

def convert_ytframe(text):
  return yt_link.sub(lambda match: yt_embed.format(match.groups()[5]), text)
```

1. How can I modify my template to exclude YouTube links from the urlize filter
2. How can I ensure that the remaining content, including YouTube videos, is properly displayed and the iframe tags are not affected by the urlize filter

Comment: Using the `safe` filter like that may make you vulnerable to XSS attacks: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/

Comment: @DanielB thanks for letting me know, what is the alternative please?

Comment: There's not really a simple answer to that, and very much depends on your use case. It looks like you're building a commenting system, so you may wish to look into "rich text" or "wysiwyg" editors, E.g., https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/

Answer (score 0):

Modify the convert_ytframe function to handle the conversion of YouTube links and keep track of them

```
 import re

yt_link = re.compile(r'(https?://)?(www\.)?((youtu\.be/)|(youtube\.com/watch/?\?v=))([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)', re.I)
yt_embed = '<iframe width="460" height="215" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{0}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'

def convert_ytframe(text):
    def replace(match):
        youtube_id = match.groups()[5]
        return yt_embed.format(youtube_id)

    return yt_link.sub(replace, text)
```

Update your Django template to apply the urlize filter only to the non-YouTube content .

Handle YouTube videos separately in your Django view .
When rendering the content in your Django view, you can replace the YouTube placeholders with the actual YouTube iframe embed code